# How to bypass object safety in Rust

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm not particularly familiar with how Rust unsafe is used, but, essentially, I need to be able to create a dynamic trait object (whose methods will never be called while it is in the form of a trait object because it gets downcasted), but the trait which I need to make the object out of has `Sized` as a super-trait, which means that, for object safety, I can't create a dynamic type.

I can't create my own trait because the trait is defined and being used by a crate that I am not the author of, so I was wondering if there is some way of bypassing the object safety requirements of trait objects.

Alternatively, if there is some equivalent to pyo3's `IntoPy<Py<PyTuple>>` that doesn't have `Sized` as a supertrait, but can be used as arguments to call a python function in `pyo3`, that would also work.

Comment: Please provide more info about your constraints. In particular, assuming you were the author of the trait, could you just remove the `: Sized` bound and it would work?

Comment: It will be good if you provide a code sketch of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a trait object out of a value but you are only going to downcast it, it sounds a lot like you want to use [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) as `Box<dyn Any>`.  This trait has a `downcast` method you can use to attempt to cast the value to a concrete type.

Comment: thank you very much, yes, I do think that that is what I am looking for.